# Parsing Excel file into CSV file

Tags: c#, performance, excel, csv

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your answers, this is moving quickly now and it's always essential to get better with design and best practice!

I am loading in an excel file to a dataset using `ExcelDataReader`. I then need to create a `*.csv` file with the data.

Currently for the excel sheet I'm working with I have about 40 columns and 30k rows of data. The approach I'm taking takes about 2 minutes to complete.

The second snippet is the offender.

```
public static Stream SaveAsCsv(Stream excelFile, string filename)
{
    MemoryStream newCSV = new MemoryStream();

    string test = excelFile.ToString();

    IExcelDataReader reader = null;
    if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(excelFile);
    }
    else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(excelFile);
    }

    //Read was empty so return a null stream in return
    if (reader == null)
        return newCSV;

    var headers = new List<string>();

    var ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true,

            ReadHeaderRow = rowReader =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    headers.Add(Convert.ToString(rowReader.GetValue(i)));
            },

            FilterColumn = (columnReader, columnIndex) =>
            !headers[columnIndex].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SKIP")
        }
    });
    var csvContent = string.Empty;
    int colCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
```

This `for` operation is what takes two minutes to complete, everything else is not a problem:

```
    for (int row_no = 0; row_no < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; row_no++)
    {
        var arr = new List<string>();
        if (row_no == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                arr.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            object[] objarr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row_no].ItemArray;

            arr = ((IEnumerable)objarr).Cast<object>()
                         .Select(x => x.ToString())
                         .ToList();
        }
        csvContent += string.Join("|", arr) + "\n";
    }


    StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(newCSV);
    csv.Write(csvContent);
    csv.Flush();
    csv.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return csv.BaseStream;
}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t This is almost the entire code for the operation, `reader` is the memory stream. The for block is what takes the time to complete.

Comment: @t3chb0t I edited the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: I'd be much better (and easier to review) if you posted complete methods (just as you have them ). You can also add comments where you think the slow part might be (or you're sure because you've measured them).

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice I have added the whole method and called out the part which is slowest based on measuring it with a stopwatch. The for loop takes ~2 minutes and the rest is instantaneous.

Comment: Do I get it correctly, both code parts belong to the same method `SaveAsCsv`. The comment inbetween is just to indicate the slow loop, right?

Comment: Yes sir that is the case

Comment: Change this `csvContent += ` to use a `StringBuilder` and measure it one more time. You should notice a big improvement :-)

Comment: @t3chbOt make this an answer.

Comment: @Heslacher too busy :-] maybe later or tomorrow as there a lot more issues... if there is still anything left for me until then.

Comment: @t3chb0t  That made a huge difference, if no answer posted tomorrow I'll post what I did based on his comment. This is running very quick now.

Comment: _if no answer posted tomorrow_ - have patience ;-) Wait a couple of days, especially if weekend is comming...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely follow [@Henrik Hansen's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/192523/59161) suggestion about separating your method into multiple APIs with one exception.

The save method should just save the stream. There is no need for it return any streams. You should already know this stream from the `CreateCsv` method.

---

Other things that you can improve are...

---

**String concatenation**

> ```
> csvContent += string.Join("|", arr) + "\n";
> ```

I'm pretty sure this is the bottleneck of you application. Strings are immutable so in order to concatenate strings, the runtime has to copy the old one and appaned something new to it. Usually this is not a big issue but since you *have about 40 columns and 30k rows of data* this is really a lot of copying. And the string is growing, so each copy operation has to handle larger and larger strings.

For frequent string manipulation, especially in loops, you should use the `StringBuilder` that does not requrie copying. There are numerous pages about this topic so if you are interested in its internals, just google for it.

---

As far as strings are concerned there is one more piece of code that isn't efficient yet.

> ```
> arr = ((IEnumerable)objarr).Cast<object>()
>              .Select(x => x.ToString())
>              .ToList();
> ```

You're materializing the `objarr` by calling `ToList`. This is not necessary at this point.

> ```
> string.Join("|", arr)
> ```

`Join` can take of enumerating it later only once. Currently your string is being created twice.

The new code could look this:

```
var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int row_no = 0; row_no < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; row_no++)
{
    if (row_no == 0)
    {
        var headers = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            headers.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName);
        }
        csvBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join("|", headers));
    }
    else
    {
        var items = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row_no].ItemArray;
        var values = ((IEnumerable)items).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString());
        csvBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join("|", values));
    }
}
```

---

**Always dispose streams**

Another bad habit of yours is to not dispose streams. If you call this method a couple of time you'll be wasting a lot of memory. You should always do it at some point either with the `using` statement or by calling `Dispose()` in a `try/finally` block.

---

**Naming**

You should pay more attention to your variable names. `arr` is a terrible name because it can stand for just anything. It harms code readability. Code should document itself. This one doesn't.

You should also be more consistent. If you name most of your variables correctly with *camelCase* then don't name others with _snake_case_ like `row_no`.

Use always strong names and as precise as you can. Not too long (if possible) but also not to short, avoid abbreviations. `columnIndex` is a good example. `row_no` should be `rowIndex`. Currently it looks like more then one person was writing this code. Each one with different coding style.

---

**{}**

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < rowReader.FieldCount; i++)
>                headers.Add(Convert.ToString(rowReader.GetValue(i)));
> ```

Always use `{}`. You can save youself hours of debugging because without them it's very easy to make a mistake.

---

**Explicit types vs var**

You mix explit types and `var`. You use them interchangeably. This makes your code look very unprovessional and messy. Pick one and stick to it. (I suggest picking `var`).

Comment: I think that the code would be even more efficient, if instead of building one huge string with `StringBuilder`, OP were to write directly into output `csv` stream on every iteration. At the very least it should reduce the memory consumption for larger files.

Comment: @NikitaB oh, good catch... definitely!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think, I would make an API with 3 overloads in order to split up the responsibility:

```
  public enum ExcelFormat
  {
    Xls = 1,
    Xlsx = 2,
  }

  public static Stream CreateCsv(string excelFileName)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(excelFileName))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("excelFileName");

    ExcelFormat format;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelFileName).ToUpper();
    switch (extension)
    {
      case ".XLS":
        format = ExcelFormat.Xls;
        break;
      case ".XLSX":
        format = ExcelFormat.Xlsx;
        break;
      default:
        throw new FileFormatException("Invalid File Format or File Name");
    }

    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(excelFileName))
    {
      return CreateCsv(stream, format);
    }
  }

  public static Stream CreateCsv(Stream excelStream, ExcelFormat format)
  {
    if (excelStream == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(excelStream));

    IExcelDataReader reader = null;

    switch (format)
    {
      case ExcelFormat.Xls:
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(excelStream);
        break;
      case ExcelFormat.Xlsx:
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(excelStream);
        break;
    }

    return CreateCsv(reader);
  }

  public static Stream CreateCsv(IExcelDataReader reader)
  {
    if (reader == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));

    DataSet dataSet = ReadData(reader);
    return WriteData(dataSet);
  }
```

---

I think, this filter isn't very reliable (one day some one has a column name containing "skip" that should not be skipped):

```
FilterColumn = (columnReader, columnIndex) => !headers[columnIndex].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SKIP")
```

If the valid column names are fairly static, I would make some kind of settings file, where the valid columns are defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
  <columns>
    <colum>AAA</colum>
    <colum>BBB</colum>
    <colum>CCC</colum>
    <colum>DDD</colum>
  </columns>
</settings>
```

If the operation is user-interactive, then it would maybe probably be better with a dialog or wizard where they could select the valid columns.

---

About performance, I think t3chb0t has said it all :-)

---

**Edit**
I've updated with

```
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(excelFileName))
    {
      return CreateCsv(stream, format);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are having a **bug** here because you will always skip the first row of the datatable.

> ```
> var csvContent = string.Empty;
> int colCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
> for (int row_no = 0; row_no < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; row_no++)
> {
>     var arr = new List<string>();
>     if (row_no == 0)
>     {
>         for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
>         {
>             arr.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName);
>         }
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         object[] objarr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row_no].ItemArray;
>
>         arr = ((IEnumerable)objarr).Cast<object>()
>                      .Select(x => x.ToString())
>                      .ToList();
>     }
>     csvContent += string.Join("|", arr) + "\n";
> }
> ```

In addition why would you want to check for `row_no == 0` for each datarow, which simply means checking this 30k times?

You should extract the retrieving of the columnnames to a separate method and if wanted int an extension method like so

```
public static IEnumerable<string> RetrieveColumnNames(this DataTable dataTable)
{
    if (dataTable == null) { yield break; }
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        yield return column.ColumnName;
    }
}
```

This

> ```
>         object[] objarr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row_no].ItemArray;
>
>         arr = ((IEnumerable)objarr).Cast<object>()
>                      .Select(x => x.ToString())
>                      .ToList();
> ```

is somehow strange itself. The `ItemArray` property of a `DataRow` is an `object[]` and if you use `string.Join()` with an `object[]` the `ToString()` method of each object will be called by it.

If reffering to a `DataRow` or `DataColumn` by using `ds.Tables[0]` more than once you should introduce a separate variable which just hold a reference to `ds.Tables[0]`.

Like @NikitaB mentioned in a comment to @t3chb0t answer

> I think that the code would be even more efficient, if instead of
>   building one huge string with `StringBuilder`, OP were to write directly
>   into output `csv` stream on every iteration. At the very least it should
>   reduce the memory consumption for larger files.

Putting this all together the former loop could look like so

```
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(newCSV);

var dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

csv.WriteLine(string.Join("|", dataTable.RetrieveColumnNames()));

for (int rowNo = 0; row_no < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowNo++)
{
    object[] objarr = dataTable.Rows[rowNo].ItemArray;
    csv.WriteLine(string.Join("|", objarr));
}
```

Comment: Mhmm... I looked at the example a couple of times but I'm still not sure where OP is skipping the first row... could you point me to the bug?

Comment: For `if (row_no == 0)` the OP only outputs the columnnames. Hence `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]` won't be written to the output.

Comment: I believe there is no bug. OP is reading an excel table... the first row is probably column names ;-)

Comment: I know, but thats why OP sets `UseHeaderRow = true` in the configuration. And believe me, I have tested this ;-)

Comment: Do you happen to know the library OP is using for reading Excel or this techinque? Honestly, I have no idea what's going on there ;-]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: You can get it by NuGet as well